# Receiving large UDP packet fails behind Linux firewall using C#

Tags: c#, sockets, ubuntu, udp, firewall

I was successfully using this code on my home computer - please note that I have minified the code in order to only show the important parts

```
Socket Sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

// Connect to the server
Sock.Connect(Ip, Port);

// Setup buffers
byte[] bufferSend = ...; // some data prepared before
byte[] bufferRec = new byte[8024];

// Send the command
Sock.Send(bufferSend, SocketFlags.None);

// UNTIL HERE EVERYTHING WORKS FINE

// Receive the answer
int ct = 0;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
while ((ct = Sock.Receive(bufferRec)) > 0)
{
     response.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(bufferRec, 0, ct));
}

// Print the result
Console.WriteLine("This is the result:\n" + response.ToString());
```

In another environment (Windows but behind an Ubuntu firewall) I have problems receiving packets with over 1472 bytes: An exception is thrown that the request timed out.

So basically I have two options:

- Either fixing the Ubuntu firewall server (how?)
- Adjusting my code (probably better option?)

How would I need to adapt my code in order to split packets in working size? I thought adjusting the variable `bufferRec = new byte[1024]` would suffice, but obviously this does not work. I get an exception then that the received package is greater than the bufferRec. Do I have to change the SocketType?

Unfortunately I do not know a lot about sockets, so your explainations would help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your packet is traveling various networks. Each network probably has its own MTU size. This is the maximum size a single packet can be.

If your data exceeds that size, the `DF` flag is checked (DF stands for Don't Fragment). If that flag is set, the packet is dropped and an ICMP response is generated.

In C# sockets, this option is controlled by the `DontFragment` property, wich defaults to `True`, hence your problem.

Note that UDP with fragmentation enabled is to be considered unreilable, since packets will probably get lost on a busy network

Comment: So what can I do? What do I need to change? Unfortunately I am querying a server that can only be contacted by UDP, so I can only change on the client-side.

Comment: you need to set `Sock.DontFragment` to false

Comment: You think that is enough? I will try it out of course when I come back home and give you feedback.

Comment: this will allow your packet to be much larger than a normal MTU (1400 bytes, give or take) but will eventually be unreilable. It will work, but some packets won't arrive to the server.

Comment: and to solve that, you need to mimic what TCP does (`ACK` each packet and resend lost ones)

Comment: Do you know why changing the network interface's MTU (on the Ubuntu server) didn't work for me? I tried changing it to 8k bytes (all requests are between 0 and 4k bytes), but the requests were still failing. What else could have been the cause? // Anyway, I'll try the DontFragment property first.

Comment: because the MTU value that wins is the smaller in the network path. So you set the value very large, but once the packet reaches another router, the MTU will probably be much much smaller

Comment: That makes sense, but it the network interfaces of the firewall were the only components in the way between my script and the server.